# How to make "navbar-fixed-bottom" slide up when button is clicked in responsive mode? (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently Twitter Bootstrap's navbar at the bottom (used as footer) slides "down" when the button is pushed on a phone screen or narrow window.

I want the menu to slide "up" instead of the default "down".. Any ideas on how I can do this with twitter bootstrap?

the code used in the view layer of the navbar footer is as follows:

```
<footer id="footer" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar dropup" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".show-footer">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse show-footer">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <%= g_about_link(yield(:title)) %>
                        <%= g_contact_link(yield(:title)) %>
                        <%= g_faq_link(yield(:title)) %>
                        <%= g_careers_link(yield(:title)) %>
                        <%= g_privacy_link(yield(:title)) %>
                        <%= g_quotes_link(yield(:title)) %>
                        <%= g_terms_link(yield(:title)) %>
                        <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/" target="_blank">News</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: can you please post some snippets or a test page .. More code more help!

Comment: heres a test page: http://quiet-waterfall-1446.heroku.com

Comment: What do you mean "slide up"? The only interpretation I can muster is for the bottom of the footer to pull away from the bottom of the viewport, leaving a gap.

Comment: Wait, I think I've figured it out. You want the entire page to scroll up so that the footer stays in view when it's expanded, right? The only alternative would be for the footer to expand over the top of the page content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the page using a show() event callback:

http://jsfiddle.net/Apx5N/2/

```
$(function() {
  $('.collapse.show-footer').on('show', function () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  });
});


<div class="container">
  ...

  <div class="nav-collapse show-footer collapse"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: excellent! you are a genius! So I'm assuming this is jQuery right? im going to try to translate it into coffeescript for readability and include in my rails project! Last question.. does the the .collapse need to be there? can it not just be .show-footer (2nd line in js)?

Comment: The .collapse class isn't required. Use whatever unique selector you like. It is jQuery, which is what Bootstrap uses. Translate away, though I'm not sure why jQuery isn't perfectly readable already.

Comment: the coffeescript translation looks something like this: jQuery ->
 $('.show-footer').on('show', ->
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow"))

Comment: For me this only work for static navbar. fixed navbar bottom not work

Answer (score 3):

For those using Bootstrap 3 the event "show" has now been renamed to "show.bs.collapse" and so the function would look like this:

```
$(function() {
$('.collapse.show-footer').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  });
});
```

[Bootstrap Collapse Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Answer (score 0):

There is one class in bootstrap which solves it all `dropup` . Use it and it will auto pop up the drop down menu's to drop-up menus

Comment: the code above seems to be the only way to do it until bootstrap makes it default behavior. theres no reason why footer-nav should slide down and not up!

Comment: the same class can be used for the footer menus as well with few lines of code

Comment: please show working css code. I'd love to see this work without javascript and only plain css.