# bootstrap navbar to animate up instead of down when collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my main nav fixed on the bottom of my page and want the navbar to animate up when clicked on instead of animate down. Can someone please help me out with this or send me in the right direction? it is not a dropdown menu i know how to make the dropdown menu drop up. when the width is a certain size it turns into a dropdown menu and i would like for it to animate to the top when clicked on instead of the bottom.
any help would be great thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918773/how-to-make-navbar-fixed-bottom-slide-up-when-button-is-clicked-in-responsive)

Comment: which didn't have a proper answer, @Schmalzy . I'd still like to see a proper answer for this, instead of scrolling the page down to view the menu. some sort of `dropup` or `collapse-up` would be nice...

Comment: Sorry @Schmalzy, no duplicate there.. I've got the same problem here. Using `navbar-fixed-bottom`, on narrow screens the navbar still opens down (off the screen for me). I think Travis wants to keep the bar at the bottom as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

- old bootstrap 2.3.0:
  http://jsfiddle.net/zalog/Apx5N/77/

  ```
  .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
      position: fixed;
  }
  ```
- latest bootstrap 3.2.0:
  http://jsfiddle.net/zalog/xC7a5/

In the latest version of bootstrap, this is the `default` functionality.